# Coreplot: Setting length of global range not working

Tags: ios, core-plot

To start with, I have a graph(Coreplot Linechart). I have set the x-range and y-range of the defaultPlotspace of the graph.

```
- (void) setUpXRangeForPlotspace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *) plotSpace {

int rangeLength = [self xRangeLength];
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(- 0.5f)    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(rangeLength + 1.0)];

}

- (void) setUpYRangeForPlotspace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *) plotSpace {

    float maxValue = [self maximumYValue];

    // length = maxvalue + (10% of maxvalue);
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f)     length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxValue + (maxValue/10.0))];
}
```

Now my task was to show a portion (region) of a graph along the x-axis according to user interaction. For that I was changing the globalXRange of plotspace.

I took two textfields from which I was getting the location and length. **btnAction:** method is fired when a button is pressed.

```
- (void) btnAction:(id) sender {

    float txt1fl = [txt1.text floatValue];
    float txt2fl = [txt2.text floatValue];


    NSLog(@"txt1fl : %f, txt2fl : %f",txt1fl,txt2fl);

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    [plotSpace setGlobalXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(txt1fl)  length:(CPTDecimalFromFloat(txt2fl))]];
    [plotSpace setGlobalYRange:plotSpace.globalYRange];

    NSLog(@"Graph Global x:%f   length:%f",CPTDecimalFloatValue(plotSpace.globalXRange.location),CPTDecimalFloatValue(plotSpace.globalXRange.length));

}
```

When I change the **location** of range and leave the **length** like that, the graph is showing the appropriate region. That is, it is scrolling to the location mentioned by the number.

And even when I am changing the **length** of the globalXRange from a **higher** to a **lower** value - for example, changing length from 5.0 to 3.0 - the graph is showing the appropriate portion. That is, it is showing a smaller region in the bigger picture.

But when I change the length of the globalXRange from **lower** to **higher** - for example, changing length 3.0 to 5.0 - the range of the graph is not increasing.

After setting the range I checked using NSLog if the globalXRange's length has changed or not. Surprisingly the length has changed according to NSLog but visually the graph has not moved nor changed its range.

I am unable to work out the solution. please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `globalXRange` and `globalYRange` limit the amount that the plot space can scroll and zoom using the built-in user interaction features. Use the `xRange` and `yRange` to control the visible part of the plots.

Comment: thank you. that solved the problem. Instead of changing the     globalXRange, now i am changing the     xRange of the plotspace.